# Combine rows of df based on sequence in 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df like this:

```
d = {'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'K', 'L', 'M'], 'col2': ['Open', 'Done', 'Open', 'Open', 'Done', 'Open'], 'col3': [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I'd like to iterate over `col3` whenever the next row is increasing, until the same value reoccurs, then combine rows/columns like this:

```
d = {'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'K', 'L', 'M'], 'col2': ['Open', 'Done', 'Open', 'Open', 'Done', 'Open'], 'col3': [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2], 'col4': ['B/Done;C/Open;K/Open', 'C/Open;K/Open', 'None', 'None', 'M/Open', 'None']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have thousands of rows, so I am trying to avoid using a `for` loop if possible.

Comment: How many rows do you have? There is likely no other way than a loop

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't perform this in a vectorial way.

Here is a working approach, but using a loop in a custom function:

```
def combine(series):
    out = []
    for s in series.iloc[1:]:
        out.append(out[-1]+';'+s if out else s)
    out = out[::-1]
    out.append(None)
    return pd.Series(out, index=series.index)

group = df['col3'].diff().eq(0)[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]

df['col4'] = (df.assign(col=df['col1']+'/'+df['col2'])
   .groupby(group, sort=False)['col']
   .apply(combine)
)
```

output:

```
  col1  col2  col3                  col4
0    A  Open     1  B/Done;C/Open;K/Open
1    B  Done     2         B/Done;C/Open
2    C  Open     3                B/Done
3    K  Open     3                  None
4    L  Done     1                M/Open
5    M  Open     2                  None
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution works only for the example i listed. but if col3 is 1,1,2,1,1,2 it should be setting col3 at index 1 and 4 which is not the case. what is the logic you used for group?

this logic identifies for me all rows that need update but i cannot apply it:

df['col3'].shift(-1)-df['col3'] if this is >0 the index needs update.

how to update your code based on this?